# Sperate PHP include files - opening and closing brackets/braces { } for if's and while loop nd closing curly brackets/braces in between files

Tags: php, include, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I am working with PHP includes i.e:

```
include_once("somephpfile.php");
```

And a CSS/HTML designer that is very problematic. I am trying to keep all PHP away from the designer, as they become very panicked : \  and they create many problems, deleting code and things and messing up everything.

So I have been using the PHP includes to add the PHP where necessary between their HTML.

The PHP works fine and there are zero bugs.

It is the separation of the PHP into multiple include files that is causing my some problems.

Following is an example of what I am trying to separate.

The PHP to be separated:

---

```
<?php
$foo = 0;
$bar = 0;

if($foo == 0){

    $foo++;
    $bar++;
    // more php code

    while($foo < 20){

        $foo++;
        $bar++;
        // more php code

    // Now write the designers HTML here in this loop
    ?>  

        <BR /> Some HTML 
        <?php echo $foo; ?>
         more html 
        <?php echo $bar; ?>
        <BR /> More HTML <BR /> <BR />

    <?php
    // Done with the designers code -Now close my PHP here

   }// END while($foo < 5)

}// END if($foo == 0)
?>
```

---

I want to separate this into 2 includes - include1.php and include2.php

And I want to have the designers code between the while loop. So what I did was this:

---

include1.php

```
   if($foo == 0){

    $foo++;
    $bar++;
    // more php code

      while($foo < 20){

        $foo++;
        $bar++;
       // more php code
   ?>
```

---

DESIGNERS HTML and a little mixed PHP

```
    <BR /> Some HTML 
    <?php echo $foo; ?>
     more html 
    <?php echo $bar; ?>
    <BR /> More HTML <BR /> <BR />
```

---

include2.php

```
    <?php
   // Done with the designers code -Now close my PHP here

  }// END while($foo < 5)

}// END if($foo == 0)
?>
```

I get an error **("Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in)**

I have multiple if's and while's and loops.

**My question is: How do I separate these braces / brackets without an error?**

**Thank you**

Comment: Looks like it makes sense to use a templating mechanism for this. Just like any cms does to separated markup from logic. ONly that in this case the markup is done by the designers. The templating systems offers you that separation.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do is just wrong. You can't break PHP control structures like `if` and `while` into multiple files. If you need to separate PHP from HTML your best choice could be [Smarty templates](http://www.smarty.net/). They will keep your HTML solid and clean, same with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inconsistent with the opening `<?php` and closing `?>` bits in your includes, if they are as posted. They need to be before and after the PHP code as usual. I'm not sure it would work even then.

Instead, you should reverse the idea and have a separate .php file for the "designer's HTML" that you can include into your PHP. That way the designer has a file with only simple PHP for echoes. This could be a suitable separation of logic and design for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/about_smarty). This will help separate the presentation aspect from PHP.